# DNS server for DMZ

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, internal-dns, dns-server

Servers are in a different subnet like 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 and there is a NAT for internet access. For example if one of my web servers ip is 192.168.1.100 inlocal then 5.5.5.100 will be my outside ip.

Now I have a DNS server and I need to resolve DMZ servers different. If someone on the outside wants to resolve xxx.com then it will be 5.5.5.100. But if my DMZ servers wants to resolve xxx.com, it should be resolved as 192.168.1.100. How can I do this with Windows Server 2012? 
 I dont want to install a new server just for local resolving. I want to do this job in one machine for both local and outside.

Comment: What about addking xxx.com to your hosts.txt in you local servers..

Comment: I have more than 50 servers in my web farm.

Comment: I think your looking at split horizon DNS.

Comment: Do the servers need to resolve eachothers names by FQDN or hostname alone? If the latter is the only requirement, host 2 zones (domain.tld and intern.domain.tld), and add the intern.domain.tld to the search suffix list on the web servers

Comment: @Mathias Only if it's a human. [Applications should never rely on search suffixes.](http://serverfault.com/q/626612/152073)