# Is There A Way To Implement WINS-like Functionality Without WINS?

Tags: linux, networking, wins

A company 'somecompany' is retiring WINS (Windows Internet Name Server) support.  This means that where the IT staff used to be able to type:

```
ssh somehost
```

They now have to type:

```
ssh somehost.somecompany.com
```

WINS has been deprecated for years.  Is there some other (preferably open source) way to implement name resolution, to simply type 'somehost' and have the lookup resolve to somehost.somecompany.com if the computer is on the somecompany.com network?

Typing those extra characters adds up.

Comment: We call it DNS. And as far as typing the fully qualified domain name, get used to it; we aren't going back. [Here's why.](http://serverfault.com/q/626612/126632)

Comment: Thanks for the reference to that discussion.  Pretty much confirmed what I suspected although I had hoped there was some technically sound solution.  One suggestion I saw on there that I liked was adding aliases to `.ssh/config` with the short host names.

Comment: A sidenote, WINS is still installed in some special case. Like to have the network neighbourhood filled for a PC over a vpn tunnel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure a DNS search suffix for your systems (probably in DHCP) of `somecompany.com` to allow resolution using just a host's short name.

Answer (score 2):

Q: Is There A Way To Implement WINS-like Functionality Without WINS?

A: Yes. Deploy a GlobalNames Zone.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731744.aspx