# Gmail mail is handled by 10 your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.gmail

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am running my own DNS server using `bind`, and I have only just noticed the output of `host -t mx gmail` on any system using my DNS server:

```
gmail mail is handled by 10 your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.gmail.
```

Looking at [this article from ICANN](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-collision-2013-12-06-en), it looks like this message means name collisions, however everything in my DNS server seems to be working fine. Also, my domain is `home.lan` so I don't see how there could be name collisions.

Is this something I should be concerned of?

**Update:**
Note that my lookups do not resolve to `127.0.53.53` like in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/626612/dns-just-started-resolving-my-server-prod-addresses-to-127-0-53-53), so I am not sure whether this is really a duplicate. In my environment, resolutions work just fine.

Comment: `gmail` is now valid gTLD domain, so you can't use it internally - http://icannwiki.com/.gmail

Comment: @Marki555 understood, but I don't use Gmail internally, the only thing I use is `.lan`. Also, why does this not happen if I run the `host` command when I am using the router's DNS?

Comment: Also `pdns-recursor` on my server returns the same as yours and according to ICANN it is correct. Why did you asked your server for `gmail` domain then?

Comment: @Marki555 I was configuring Postfix for SMTP delivery to a Gmail address, so while checking if everything was correct I also happened to run that command. What I noticed is that if I use my router's DNS server, I get a list of Gmail FQDN's, but if I use my DNS server, I get that message. To me it doesn't make sense because yes, gmail is indeed handled by my DNS server, that's why I have a DNS server in the first place :D I don't see how this can be a problem though, unless I am completely misunderstanding the message

Comment: No, gmail is not handling email at the `.gmail` domain, only at `gmail.com`. Your server does what browsers do - add the `.com` domain automatically if there are no dots in the domain name.

Comment: @Marki555 hah, I knew it was something this simple XD