# How to ping a server on a different network by the hostname only?

Tags: domain-name-system, multiple-instances

have two networks that I am connected to via my computer, two different routers and all.  This computer is connected to a windows domain "Domain A", I can resolve the IP from any Computer Name from CMD/Ping on the same Domain A network.  But on a different NIC on the same computer, I can't resolve Domain B computers just by the host name alone, I need the FQDN (like machinename1.domain.local) when pinging Domain B computers.  How can I suppress the fact that I need the FQDN?

Hope this makes sense, this is the only way that I know of how to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the name of Domain B to your DNS Suffix Search List. Either manually through IPv4 settings -> Advanced -> DNS, or automatically through Group Policy.

Comment: Warning: Use of domain suffix search list is bad practice and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @Michael Hampton: Can you expand on that? One obvious drawback is the potential confusion if machines in different domains have identical host names, but other than that? I ask since this obviously is how Microsoft handles things even for sub domains in a forest - not that I agree with all of Microsoft’s choices.

Comment: The big one is your DNS queries leaking onto the Internet and getting resolved into unexpected addresses. See [DNS just started resolving my server.prod addresses to 127.0.53.53](https://serverfault.com/q/626612/126632) for some discussion of this.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the illumination! I learned something new.